# Q: Where do I find my files? There are only .LOCK files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I simply need to merge 2 files, however I'm unable to figure out where they are saved.

When following the path displayed in ArcMap it only leads me to the documents folder and all I can find are the needed files ending with.LOCK. I'm unable to work with those; from what I've read this is intended?

How exactly do I find out where the unlocked data is saved?

Edit: Adding some screenshots now

This is how it looks like in ArcMap. The files I need are marked in red.
[image]

When I try to go to the data source (C:Users\s14d4e\documents...) I look at this. Those .LOCK files disappear from the folder when I close ArcMap.[image]

Comment: Maybe it is locked because it is opened in Arcgis? Isn't it possible to choose layers already loaded (like yours as I understood well)?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the "documents folder" (like the name). I expect that your data source is not shapefile at all, and that expectation is causing your confusion.

Comment: @Mazu_R I couldn't find the data when ArcMap was closed. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong folder? According to a support site it appears to have something to do with geodatabases... but that info still didn't help at all.

Comment: @Vince I'm pretty sure I'm working with shapefiles... I converted some GPX datasets into points, and those dots that appear on the screen are definetely vector data. I'm going to provide you some screenshots to clear things up...

Comment: I'm **absolutely** sure you are not working with shapefiles, but instead with file geodatabase (the "documents" directory ends in ".gdb", right?) "Shapefile" is a specific file format, not a generic term for vector data.

Comment: @Vince You're totally right. Thanks for clearing things up. So the files I need are located in a geodatabase package. Is there still a way to access those files separately so I can merge them?

Comment: Any GIS utility than can merge data sources will know how to read file geodatabase table. Please rewrite the question to focus on your actual problem, not this distraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're working in the default geodatabase (Default.gdb) in your My Documents folder (probably here : C:\Users\Yourlogin\Documents).

Try going to this directory from ArcCatalog and look into the geodatabase, I guess your layers are there. You can export them from Arccatalog into shapefile for example, but you should be able to merge them regardless to the place they are located.